# Responsive css table for huge data set

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking for a quick way to get a responsive html table for a huge set of data (more than 500 row with 15 columns by row).
I tried many javascript solutions like footable but it's really too slow.

The [footable](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/) render is perfect but I would like to find a similar solution with only css tricks.

The main goal is to have a normal table for desktop and a partial table with only some columns displayed in mobile version and a click action that expand the rest of the columns Under the current table row like footable.

html example

```
<table class="f-tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>d1</th>
      <th>d2</th>
      <th>d3</th>
      <th>d4</th>
      <th>d5</th>
      <th>d6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">item 1</td>
      <td class="d1">val 1</td>
      <td class="d2">val 2</td>
      <td class="d3">val 3</td>
      <td class="d4">val 4</td>
      <td class="d5">val 5</td>
      <td class="d6">val 6</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css example

```
.f-tab {
  min-width: 320px;
}
.f-tab th, .f-tab td {
  display: none;
}
.f-tab tr.visible td {
  display: block;
}
.f-tab td.name, .f-tab td.d1, .f-tab td.d3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .f-tab th, .f-tab td {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
.f-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

js example

```
$(".f-tab tr").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("visible");
});
```

in my example, I want to display the column "name", "d1" and "d3" as table columns and have the other columns in display block Under the current row when I click on a tr.

```
___________________
name  |  d1  |  d3
d2
d4
d5
d6
___________________
```

I tried at first with nested ul/li but I couldn't get something good.

Comment: Can you show us some code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: You might find that your requirements go above and beyond what the html table was designed to handle. I think any UX expert would agree that there's absolutely no reason to display 500 rows at a time. I suggest paging them into results of no more than 100 for example.

Comment: @AndyNoelker Yes, I'm prepairing it.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan It's a special requirement and there is many filters/sorting and comparisons.